# cmake: How to specify weak dependency for dynamically loaded shared library

Tags: c++, build, cmake, dependencies, shared-libraries

I have a file a.cpp, part of shared library A, that loads another shared library B. Now I want to express in cmake that every time A is built, B should also be built. I do not need a "build-before" dependency: cmake should not try to build B before A, because in some cases cyclic dependencies will prevent this. So ADD_DEPENDENCIES(A B) is not possible. I also do not want to add B to the interface link libraries, since it should not be linked to other libraries somewhere else.

Bonus points for being able to specify the dependency on a.cpp, so it's not necessary to search for users of the file.

Comment: Found any solution, workaround for that?